Continued fractions convergents proofs
Given a continued fraction, let $ \frac{p_n}{q_n} $ and $ \frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}} $ be two consecutive convergents. The proof states:
$ 
|x - \frac{p_n}{q_n}| \leq \frac{2}{2q_n} 
$
Using the Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean (AM-GM) inequality, the proof proceeds as follows:
$ 
\left| \frac{p_n}{q_n} - \frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}} \right| \leq \frac{2}{q_n q_{n+1}} 
$
By considering the difference between ( x ) and the two convergents, we have:
$ 
\left| x - \frac{p_n}{q_n} \right| + \left| x - \frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}} \right| \leq \frac{2}{2q_n} + \frac{2}{2q_{n+1}} 
$
Which simplifies to:
$ 
x - \frac{p_n}{q_n} \leq \frac{2}{2q_n} \quad \text{or} \quad x - \frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}} \leq \frac{2}{2q_{n+1}} 
$
Can someone please why the case where both of the above inequalities are true is not possible?
